# PHP - Loop through POST values N times

Tags: php

I'm working with an API that sends a request to my server with some POST values, including this one:

```
'NumMedia' => '1'
```

The value for NumMedia determines how many additional parameters will be received. For example if NumMedia = 1 I will get 2 additional parameters like this:

```
'MediaContentType0' => 'image/jpeg'
'MediaUrl0' => 'https://api.server.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxx',
```

If NumMedia is greater than 1 I'll get an additional set of parameters like this:

```
'MediaContentType0' => 'image/jpeg'
'MediaUrl0' => 'https://api.server.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxxxxx'
'MediaContentType1' => 'image/jpeg'
'MediaUrl1' => 'https://api.server.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/zzzzzzzz'
```

and so on, where the first parameters end with 0 and increment by 1 for every additional returned set of parameters.

What I would like to do is, based on the number of parameters indicated by the value of the NumMedia parameter, loop through each of these and set them into variables and then write out some database records. Something along the lines of:

```
if (isset($_POST['NumMedia']) && $_POST['NumMedia'] !== '') {
    $totalParams = $_POST['NumMedia'];
    $counter = 0;

    // set a variable for the first set of parameters
    $mediaContentType = $_POST['NumMediaXXX'] // XXX = $counter
    $mediaURL = $_POST['MediaUrlXXX'] // XXX = $counter

    // save these variables to database record
    // increment counter to get next set of parameters
    // exit when $counter = $totalParams

    $counter ++; 
}
```

I can conceptually see what I need to do just not sure how to get the loop going and to reference a dynamic POST parameter and exit the loop when I hit the number of expected parameters?

Comment: WHY NOT Loop through all post values `foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) { // your code here }`

Comment: I need to group the parameters that can exist {N} times, which are the MediaUrl{N} and the MediaContentType{N} parameters, and for each set of these write them out to a record in a database. It feels like I need to loop through these as I know based on NumMedia how many to expect.

Comment: WHY NOT Loop through all post values `foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {if(strpos($key, 'NumMedia') !== 'false'){ // your code here }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the value through loops.

```
if (isset($_POST['NumMedia']) && $_POST['NumMedia'] !== '') {

    $totalParams = $_POST['NumMedia'];

    for($i=0; $i<$totalParams; $i++)
    {
        // set a dynamic variables
        ${"mediaContentType" . $i}  = $_POST['mediaContentType'.$i]; // XXX = $counter
        ${"mediaURL" . $i} = $_POST['MediaUrl'.$i]; // XXX = $counter
    }

}
```

You have to set the value in dynamic variable and can access the value by `$mediaContentType0 , $mediaURL0, $mediaContentType1 , $mediaURL1` and so on....

Comment: he wants to save the data to the db inside the loop, there is not need for dynamic variables, just use $mediaContentType and $mediaURL

Comment: Or use an array if you want to use the values outside the loop, the dynamic variable sounds like a weird/harder to implement solution to me.

Comment: @phobia82 let him decide what he wants to do with the variable :P